# Adding to XML file using PHP with SimpleXML error

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am using a simple simplexml php file to add to my XML file. For some reason it is not placing the record into the XML file and my logs are showing

> PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function addChild()

Wondering can someone help me out? Might be something really simple. I am attaching the PHP code and the XML file.

PHP:

```
<?php
$file = 'news.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);

$story = $xml->news->story;

$story->addChild('storyid', '33');
$story->addChild('story_pic', 'images/test.jpg');
$story->addChild('story_title', 'Your Title');
$story->addChild('story', 'This is a test story');
$story->addChild('story_date', '01/01/2001');

$xml->asXML($file);
?>
```

XML

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" standalone="yes"?>
<news>
    <story>
        <storyid>1</storyid>
        <story_pic>http://portfoliotheme.org/enigmatic/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2012/07/placeholder1.jpg</story_pic>
        <story_title>My Test News Story</story_title>
        <story>fdsfsfsdfdsfdsfsfsdfdsfsfdffsfdssfd</story>
        <story_date>22/01/2016</story_date>
    </story>
    <story>
        <storyid>2</storyid>
        <story_pic>http://portfoliotheme.org/enigmatic/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2012/07/placeholder1.jpg</story_pic>
        <story_title>My Test News Story2</story_title>
        <story>fdsfsfsdfdsfdsfsfsdfdsfsfdffsfdssfd</story>
        <story_date>22/01/2016</story_date>
    </story>
</news>
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$story`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely, this has been aswered thousands times but:

```
$file = './news.xml';

$xml = simplexml_load_file($file);
// `$xml` presents root item (`news`) of your xml tree

// add new `story` to your root item (`news`)
$new_story = $xml->addChild('story');

// add items to newly added `$new_story` element
$new_story->addChild('storyid', '33');
$new_story->addChild('story_pic', 'images/test.jpg');
$new_story->addChild('story_title', 'Your Title');
$new_story->addChild('story', 'This is a test story');
$new_story->addChild('story_date', '01/01/2001');

// save as XML
$xml->asXML($file);
```